# Insert some dynamic JSON into a JSON structure

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

In my code below I am trying to insert some `JSON` into a `JSON` structure, however, I cannot seem to access it. Please see my code below where I am trying to insert `thisCard` into the `elements` section of this responseJSON

structure of responseJSON

```
{  
   "messages":[  
      {  
         "attachment":"",
         "type":"template",
         "payload":{  
            "template_type":"generic",
            "elements":[  

            ]
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

my code

```
 request(options, function (error, response, results) {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);
    var json = JSON.parse(results);
    //console.log(json);
    responseJSON.messages.elements= [];

    for (var i = 0; i < json.results.length; i++)
    {
        var thisCard = {
            "title": json.results[i].headline,
            "image_url": json.results[i].image,
            "subtitle":"",
            "buttons":[
            {
              "type":"web_url",
              "url":json.results[i].externalurl,
              "title":"Summary"
            }
          ]
        }
       responseJSON.messages.elements.push(thisCard);

    }
  });
```

This is not working so I would like to know how I can fix it.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: And by the format of responseJSON that you have mentioned in the question. You should access your elements like this. responseJSON.messages[0].payload.elements. Please check your object structure carefully.

Comment: According to your code, `responseJSON` is a string ..?

Comment: The javascript object declaring of `thisCard` is wrong. Remove all quotes (`"`) from the object and try. **JSON** is *Javascript Serialised Object Notation*, it isn't a Javascript object.